# I get a false link for a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I created this route:

```
get "patientform/create/(:department_id)/(:form_model)/(:form_id)/(:formpath)", to: 'patientform#create', as: 'create_patientform'
```

Later i call it in my view:

```
<%= link_to 'Form', create_patientform_path(@current_department.id, @patient.class.name, nil, "patients.form"), :class => 'btn btn-info btn-xs' %>
```

How you can see in my link `:form_id` is defined as nil
This creates this link:

```
http://localhost:3000/patientform/create/2/Patient/patients.form
```

**But i would need this link:**

```
http://localhost:3000/patientform/create/2/Patient//patients.form
```

Becaus in my controller i save it like this:

```
   def create
    a = Patientform.new
    a.secure = SecureRandom.hex 3
    a.department_id = params[:department_id]
    a.form_id = params[:form_id]
    a.form_model = params[:form_model]
    a.formpath = params[:formpath]
    if a.save
        flash[:notice] = "Patienten Formular jetzt vefügbar zu finden unter #{a.secure}"
        redirect_to :back 
    end
  end
```

How you can see the false link provokes that later not the `form_id` is saved as `nil` but insted `formpath` is `nil`

```
=> #<Patientform id: 4, department_id: "2", form_model: "Patient", form_id: "pat
ients.form", secure: "f7a58b", formpath: nil, created_at: "2013-11-15 11:19:53", upda
ted_at: "2013-11-15 11:19:53">
```

Comment: At any moment is your `form_path` will be `nil` or is it just the `form_id` ?

Comment: the problem is that the link goes to `http://localhost:3000/patientform/create/2/Patient/patients.form` and because that rails thinks `patient.form` is form_id but it is formpath

Comment: yes I understood that but just want to confirm whether can `form_path` be nil for any condition ?

Comment: form path is always defined but form_id not

Comment: You gave me a good idea i think i culd simly change the sequence of the tw params!

Comment: Yes that's what I was going to suggest you

Comment: Please write it as a answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your routes as

```
get "patientform/create/(:department_id)/(:form_model)/(:formpath)/(:form_id)", to: 'patientform#create', as: 'create_patientform'
```

and your `link_to` to

```
<%= link_to 'Form', create_patientform_path(@current_department.id, @patient.class.name, "patients.form", nil), :class => 'btn btn-info btn-xs' %>
```

so that it takes the `form_path` first and then the `form_id`